# Customizing Stratus 2 Beta player: how to remove buttons

Tags: button, widget, soundcloud, soundcloud-stratus

I've deployed my [Stratus 2 Beta](http://www.stratus.sc/) on my site, and I'm wondering as far as customization goes, is it possible to remove the "share," "comment," and "favorite" buttons from the player?

I was originally thinking including something along the lines of, for instance,

```
#stratus #player ul#buttons li.sharing a { display:none; }
```

in my "stratus.css" file, but this has brought me no success, even though

```
#stratus #player ul#buttons li.soundcloud a { display:none; }
```

gets rid of the SoundCloud icon - as done on [this site](http://sufista.com/).

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, it works via the inspector for me. Check that the player is actually pointing to the css file that you are hosting though. I think there's a external css file that the player links to. Have a look in the js for a link to a css file hosted else where.

```
#stratus #player ul#buttons li{
 display:none;
}
```